# Vue 3 Template Fragments creating errors

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix, laravel-mix-vue3

-- Update --

I forgot to mention for this issue that I am using Laravel Mix to bundle my code.

`webpack.mix.js`

```js
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
mix
  .js("src/js/index.js", "dist/js")
  .vue()
  .version()
  .js("src/js/popup.js", "dist/js")
  .vue()
  .version()
  .js("src/js/background.js", "dist/js")
  .version()
  .sass("src/css/main.scss", "dist/css")
  .sass("src/css/popup.scss", "dist/css")
  .copy("src/assets", "dist/assets")
  .copy("src/html", "dist/html")
  .copy("src/manifest.json", "dist")
  .setPublicPath("./")
  .options({ processCssUrls: false });
```

When I have it set like this, webpack uses `Vue 2` by default. To clarify, `Vue 2` works perfectly fine for my project. I just want the additional functionality of `Vue 3`.

From the [documentation that's listed on Laravel Mix](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/vue), I should be doing this in order to specify `Vue 3`

```js
mix.js('src/app.js', 'dist').vue({ version: 3 });
```

When I configure my `webpack.mix.js` like this, it ends up throwing the error `Can't resolve 'vue' in path/to/file`

-- Original --

Trying to use Fragments in Vue 3 but they are not working.

Here is my code

```js
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div v-if="tab === 'options'">
      <Options />
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="tab === 'updates'">
      <Updates />
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="tab === 'account'">
      <Account />
    </div>
  </div>
  <md-bottom-bar md-type="shift">
    <md-bottom-bar-item
      @click="($event) => changeTab($event, 'options')"
      id="bottom-bar-item-options"
      md-label="Options"
      md-icon="home"
    />
    <md-bottom-bar-item
      @click="($event) => changeTab($event, 'updates')"
      id="bottom-bar-item-updates"
      md-label="Updates"
      md-icon="pages"
    />
    <md-bottom-bar-item
      @click="($event) => changeTab($event, 'account')"
      id="bottom-bar-item-account"
      md-label="Account"
      md-icon="favorite"
    />
  </md-bottom-bar>
</template>
```

Here is the error:

`Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them  instead.`

After reading the [documentation](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/new/fragments.html#_2-x-syntax), it mentions that : `In 3.x, components now can have multiple root nodes! However, this does require developers to explicitly define where attributes should be distributed.`

I don't think I'm passing any attributes though. Without my knowledge, could I still be running Vue 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see this code should work perfectly in vue3. So it actually might be a versioning issue.

Check your package.json for "vue" the version should be 3.x.x.
After changing it to 3.x.x you will need to run `npm install` or `yarn install`.

And a little tip instead of multiple v-ifs you could use dynamic components:
`<component :is="tab"></component>`

See: https://vuejs.org/v3/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: Thank you for you response! I actually edited my answer above. Since I am using Laravel Mix to bundle everything together, I discovered that my error stems from the file I just edited.